# Powershell script for set default associaltions/programs for all users on Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, internet-explorer, adobe, default-programs

I have a problem with how to set up the same default programs for all users in windows 10 after logging in to the station.

I need to change Edge to IE and Edge to Adobe Acrobat reader.

I want every user to have the same default programs after signing in.

It's in a company with 3000 stations, so I can't do it manually on every station, but after upgrading to Windows 10 I can run a script ...

I would like to do it:

1) Internet Explorer as your default browser
2) Adobe acrobat Reader as default software on PDF

Bonus:
3) Add the IE icon to the desktop
4) Edge icon removed from desktop

I have no idea how to do it. Ideal would be some script ...

Answer (score 0):

I think GPO is a better way to achieve this. Basically, set your machine up with whatever defaults you want, [export the XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/export-or-import-default-application-associations) using commands, modify the XML to remove any defaults you don't want to set via GPO, and then use that XML as your GPO config file.

Here's [a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/set-the-default-browser-using-group-policy) about setting the default browser using Group Policy and [an article](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AdminGuide/pdfviewer.html) about setting default PDF viewer, please check it for more information.

And for the shortcut on desktop, you can refer to [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1356173/shortcut-on-desktop-for-all-users-of-a-single-computer-using-gpo) and [this article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2014/02/17/adding-shortcuts-on-desktop-using-group-policy-preferences-in-windows-8-and-windows-8-1/).